# How to add some specific content to bottom of every category page in magento1.x?

Tags: magento-1.9, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to add some content to bottom of every category product list page. The content should change depends-upon the category without editing code or layout xml file ?

Answer (score 0):

I would create for every category a CMS Block with the content and set this block after the content in the category custom layout update.

After creating a CMS Block for the category, go in adminhtml to the category. Open the tab `custom design` and add this xml in `Custom Layour Update`

```
<reference name="content">
    <block type="cms/block" name="cat_1_content">
        <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>cat_test</block_id></action>
    </block>
</reference>
```

Change the block_id `cat_test` and the block should appear after you content. Repeat this for every category. Don't forget to flush the cache.

I think it's the best way to do it without changing code. The benefit of the cms block is, you can use the default Magento editor.

Answer (score 0):

You're best creating a category attribute (text area) which is visible on all category pages like category description, if text is provided for a category it displays on category page else it doesn't.
You can create a module by following this [atwix tutorial](https://www.atwix.com/magento/add-category-attribute/)

Comment: I thought about the same solution, but the OP don't want to do it with code.